# Iterating through nested JSON object with variable Key Names

Tags: javascript, json

updated -- as the help provided was still not returning the desired results and thought that it could be in regards to how I presented the question

I am new to JSON and Struggling to work with this result in Javascript.

I am using this fetch to get a response that is returned as an object with nested objects and I am struggling to filter the results for the category with the value "mobile" only

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: No need for jQuery (`$`). You can use native JavaScript. Also, please post the actual JSON example (your post has no JSON) or the actual JavaScript object. Also the code you've posted seems wrong.

Comment: that piece of code you shared is not removing anything from the object

Comment: That's not JSON. JSON uses double quotes, not single quotes, and requires that keys be quoted.

Comment: In `$.map()`, the callback arguments are `i, val`, not `val, i`. The latter is correct for the standard JS `map()` and `forEach()` methods.

Comment: If you only want to process mobile category, try `if (val.category == 'mobile')` in the function.

Comment: If you want to create a new array with just these, use `testResults.filter(val => val.category == 'mobile')`

Comment: @Barmar that won't do. You forgot category is inside another key so it has to be like this `const result = testResults.filter(val => val.android8_gmailapp_pixel2_lm.category == 'mobile');`

Comment: yeah lol but then again that is not a valid object, with the same key name

Comment: Your data is not valid. Is it supposed to be an array of objects or a single object? You're missing the key for the second property.

Answer (score 2):

If your response is an array of objects, where each object has a varying key and an associated object, you can use `Object.values` to grab the associated object, and check the `category` of the first value.

```js
const response = [{
  android8_gmailapp_pixel2_lm: {
    category: "web",
    client: "Gmail App",
    display_name: "Gmail App Pixel 2",
    id: "android8_gmailapp_pixel2_lm",
    os: "Android 8",
    screenshots: {
      default: 'https://images.emailonacid.com/d2ViL3BHeWNzYWpRZzd…QUzFkSy9hbmRyb2lkOF9nbWFpbGFwcF9waXhlbDJfbG0ucG5n',
    },
    status: "Complete",
    thumbnail: "https://images.emailonacid.com/d2ViL3BHeWNzYWpRZzd5Y1JoY3piUXJDbXBwdFpiWGhOOFN0bGROZkdLN1JQUzFkSy9hbmRyb2lkOF9nbWFpbGFwcF9waXhlbDJfbG1fdG4ucG5n"
  },
}, {
  android8_gmailapp_pixel2_lm: {
    category: "mobile",
    client: "Gmail App",
    display_name: "Gmail App Pixel 2",
    id: "android8_gmailapp_pixel2_lm",
    os: "Android 10",
    screenshots: {
      default: 'https://images.emailonacid.com/d2ViL3BHeWNzYWpRZzd…QUzFkSy9hbmRyb2lkOF9nbWFpbGFwcF9waXhlbDJfbG0ucG5n',
    },
    status: "Complete",
    thumbnail: "https://images.emailonacid.com/d2ViL3BHeWNzYWpRZzd5Y1JoY3piUXJDbXBwdFpiWGhOOFN0bGROZkdLN1JQUzFkSy9hbmRyb2lkOF9nbWFpbGFwcF9waXhlbDJfbG1fdG4ucG5n"
  }
}];

const filteredResults = response.filter(obj =>
  (([{ category }]) => category === 'mobile')
  (Object.values(obj)));

console.log(filteredResults);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: shouldn't your `response` object be an array of objects instead? can't have an object with same keys

Comment: @ChrisG I misunderstood the structure of the data the way is was presented, I will address this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash `pickBy`:

```js
const results ={android8_gmailapp_pixel2_lm:{category:"web",client:"Gmail App",display_name:"Gmail App Pixel 2",id:"android8_gmailapp_pixel2_lm",os:"Android 8",screenshots:{default:"https://images.emailonacid.com/d2ViL3BHeWNzYWpRZzd…QUzFkSy9hbmRyb2lkOF9nbWFpbGFwcF9waXhlbDJfbG0ucG5n"},status:"Complete",thumbnail:"https://images.emailonacid.com/d2ViL3BHeWNzYWpRZzd5Y1JoY3piUXJDbXBwdFpiWGhOOFN0bGROZkdLN1JQUzFkSy9hbmRyb2lkOF9nbWFpbGFwcF9waXhlbDJfbG1fdG4ucG5n"},android8_gmailapp_pixel2_lm:{category:"mobile",client:"Gmail App",display_name:"Gmail App Pixel 2",id:"android8_gmailapp_pixel2_lm",os:"Android 10",screenshots:{default:"https://images.emailonacid.com/d2ViL3BHeWNzYWpRZzd…QUzFkSy9hbmRyb2lkOF9nbWFpbGFwcF9waXhlbDJfbG0ucG5n"},status:"Complete",thumbnail:"https://images.emailonacid.com/d2ViL3BHeWNzYWpRZzd5Y1JoY3piUXJDbXBwdFpiWGhOOFN0bGROZkdLN1JQUzFkSy9hbmRyb2lkOF9nbWFpbGFwcF9waXhlbDJfbG1fdG4ucG5n"}};

const filteredResults = _.pickBy(results, { category: 'mobile' });
console.log(filteredResults);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help thus far but I am still struggling so I have updated the request

Comment: Please add the valid json then, I don't see any data in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your test data is an array of objects (as current form is not correct),

```
var testData = [
  {android8_gmailapp_pixel2_lm: {
    category: "web",
    client: "Gmail App",
    display_name: "Gmail App Pixel 2",
    id: "android8_gmailapp_pixel2_lm",
    os: "Android 8",
    screenshots: {
      default: 'https://images.emailonacid.com/d2ViL3BHeWNzYWpRZzd…QUzFkSy9hbmRyb2lkOF9nbWFpbGFwcF9waXhlbDJfbG0ucG5n',
    },
    status: "Complete",
    thumbnail: "https://images.emailonacid.com/d2ViL3BHeWNzYWpRZzd5Y1JoY3piUXJDbXBwdFpiWGhOOFN0bGROZkdLN1JQUzFkSy9hbmRyb2lkOF9nbWFpbGFwcF9waXhlbDJfbG1fdG4ucG5n"
  }
  },
  {
    android8_gmailapp_pixel2_lm: {
      category: "mobile",
      client: "Gmail App",
      display_name: "Gmail App Pixel 2",
      id: "android8_gmailapp_pixel2_lm",
      os: "Android 10",
      screenshots: {
        default: 'https://images.emailonacid.com/d2ViL3BHeWNzYWpRZzd…QUzFkSy9hbmRyb2lkOF9nbWFpbGFwcF9waXhlbDJfbG0ucG5n'
      },
      status: "Complete",
      thumbnail: "https://images.emailonacid.com/d2ViL3BHeWNzYWpRZzd5Y1JoY3piUXJDbXBwdFpiWGhOOFN0bGROZkdLN1JQUzFkSy9hbmRyb2lkOF9nbWFpbGFwcF9waXhlbDJfbG1fdG4ucG5n"
    }
  }
  ];
```

and also assuming you will have more devices in the array, the following should work just fine:

```
let newList = [];
testData.forEach(device => {
    let idx = Object.keys(device)[0];
    if (device[idx].category === "mobile") {
        newList.push(device[idx]);
    };
});
```

Then you should get a list of matches as follows:

```
[
  {
    category: 'mobile',
    client: 'Gmail App',
    display_name: 'Gmail App Pixel 2',
    id: 'android8_gmailapp_pixel2_lm',
    os: 'Android 10',
    screenshots: {
      default: 'https://images.emailonacid.com/d2ViL3BHeWNzYWpRZzd…QUzFkSy9hbmRyb2lkOF9nbWFpbGFwcF9waXhlbDJfbG0ucG5n'
    },
    status: 'Complete',
    thumbnail: 'https://images.emailonacid.com/d2ViL3BHeWNzYWpRZzd5Y1JoY3piUXJDbXBwdFpiWGhOOFN0bGROZkdLN1JQUzFkSy9hbmRyb2lkOF9nbWFpbGFwcF9waXhlbDJfbG1fdG4ucG5n'
  }
]
```

```js
// Online Javascript Editor for free
// Write, Edit and Run your Javascript code using JS Online Compiler
var a = [
  {android8_gmailapp_pixel2_lm: {
    category: "web",
    client: "Gmail App",
    display_name: "Gmail App Pixel 2",
    id: "android8_gmailapp_pixel2_lm",
    os: "Android 8",
    screenshots: {
      default: 'https://images.emailonacid.com/d2ViL3BHeWNzYWpRZzd…QUzFkSy9hbmRyb2lkOF9nbWFpbGFwcF9waXhlbDJfbG0ucG5n',
    },
    status: "Complete",
    thumbnail: "https://images.emailonacid.com/d2ViL3BHeWNzYWpRZzd5Y1JoY3piUXJDbXBwdFpiWGhOOFN0bGROZkdLN1JQUzFkSy9hbmRyb2lkOF9nbWFpbGFwcF9waXhlbDJfbG1fdG4ucG5n"
  }
  },
  {
    android8_gmailapp_pixel2_lm: {
      category: "mobile",
      client: "Gmail App",
      display_name: "Gmail App Pixel 2",
      id: "android8_gmailapp_pixel2_lm",
      os: "Android 10",
      screenshots: {
        default: 'https://images.emailonacid.com/d2ViL3BHeWNzYWpRZzd…QUzFkSy9hbmRyb2lkOF9nbWFpbGFwcF9waXhlbDJfbG0ucG5n'
      },
      status: "Complete",
      thumbnail: "https://images.emailonacid.com/d2ViL3BHeWNzYWpRZzd5Y1JoY3piUXJDbXBwdFpiWGhOOFN0bGROZkdLN1JQUzFkSy9hbmRyb2lkOF9nbWFpbGFwcF9waXhlbDJfbG1fdG4ucG5n"
    }
  }
  ]
  let newList = [];
a.forEach(device => {
    let idx = Object.keys(device)[0];
    if (device[idx].category === "mobile") {
        newList.push(device[idx]);
    };
});
console.log(newList);
```